# Caracteres se repetindo em descoberta de String [Python]

Tags: python

O Objetivo aqui é descobrir as senhas, na tentativa e erro mesmo, e ta tudo ocorrendo bem enquanto as letras, mas **quando chegam nos números, eles se repetem** por um motivo que eu realmente não entendo. Se alguém conseguir achar o erro no código, fico grato.

```
import random
senha='TasLAVa4554'
alfa='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
num='123456789'
def breakK(x):
    ans=''
    for y in senha:        
        for z in alfa:
            if str(y)==str(z):
                print('Verificando aspectos...')
                ans+=str(z.upper())
            if str(y)==str(z.lower()):
                print('Verificando aspectos...')
                ans+=str(z.lower())
            else:
                print('Testando...')
                for n in num:
                    if str(y)==str(n):
                        print('Verificando aspectos')
                        ans+=str(n)
                    else:
                        print('Verificando aspectos')

    print(ans)
####
print(breakK(senha))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repare nos loops. O primeiro itera sobre cada caractere da senha, o segundo sobre cada caractere de alfa. Nesse tem um if com um else e nesse else vc itera sobre num. Isso quer dizer que toda vez que entrar no else, que se repete para cada caractere de alfa, vai testar num.
O `for n in num:` deve ficar no mesmo nível do `for z in alfa:`